# The set where $f_n \to f$ is measurable? A question concerning Paul Mayer's Book

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

On the book Probability and Potentials of Paul Mayer page 9 one reads:

[image]

Is there an example of a sequence of measurable functions taking values in a incomplete metric space such that the set where $f_n$ converges is not measurable?

Comment: Nice question. Just as a note (not necessarily to you, but also to others looking at this question): The usual proof uses that the set where the sequence converges is exactly the set where the sequence is Cauchy (for complete spaces). Of course, this equivalence fails for incomplete spaces.